# How to use customer attribute for the not logged in customer (Guest Customer)?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, custom-attributes, newsletter, customer-attribute

Is there any why to use customer attribute for the guest customer(s)/user(s). Like I have a news letter with which I am getting **`subscriber Email, Name, D.O.B., Country,`** all this information are getting stored in new columns
of `newsletter_subscriber` table as because I have created new columns for this table.

Now the problem is users who are customers of my site we can get these information from the customer table but as newsletters can be subscribed by guests as well is there any way to use these attributes for guest users?

Comment: Please, questions is not clear what exactly you are trying to say?

Comment: @pramod I want to use customer attributes to manage details (name, dob, country, email) of newsletter subscribers which includes customers & guest users both.

Comment: On email you can get record of customer and subscribe user then you can different customers by customer group whether it is guest or customer.